# VB.NET - How to get Assembly from PropertyInfo?

Tags: vb.net, .net-assembly, propertyinfo

I need to be able to dynamically instantiate an object using reflection. I have a `PropertyInfo` at this point and need to get the `Assembly` of this object before I can call the `CreateInstance` method.

The code looks like this:

```
Dim subObjectPropInfo As PropertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(baseObject, "Name")
Dim asm As Assembly = ?????
Dim subObjType As Type = asm.GetType(subObjectPropInfo.PropertyType.FullName)
Dim subObject As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(subObjType)
```

The question is: How can I get the assembly for the object I need to instantiate from a `PropertyInfo`object ? Is it possible ? If not, what is the way to do it ?

I use to have always the same assembly so the way to do it was not really dynamic.  Now that objects come from multiple assemblies, it cannot be done the way it used to be.

Comment: Note the third line can be simplified to `Dim subObjType As Type = subObjectPropInfo.PropertyType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the PropertyType.Assembly properties from the PropertyInfo object.

```
subObjectPropInfo.PropertyType.Assembly
```

Comment: This gives the declaring type assembly (assembly of `baseObject`) and not the assembly of the object in the `subObjectPropInfo` property.

Comment: Will subObjectPropInfo.PropertyType.DeclaringType.Assembly do it instead?

Comment: I've edited the answer as it worked with `PropertyType.Assemble`.  All credit to you for giving the hint to find it! ;-)